# Encrypt large file and add to ZIP

Tags: c#, file, encryption, zip

my goal is to encrypt large (cca 10 GB) input file and append it to an existing System.IO.Packaging Package. I can use .NET Framework 3.5 only and no third-party libraries.

I tried maybee ten  methods with no success. I tried to read the input to Stream, encrypt it and save to PackagePart. I tried to read the input file byte after byte, then encrypt byte read and append it to Stream from PackagePart too. Everytime I found a new issue (e.g. CryptoStream does not supports seeking and so on).

Could you show me the right way, please?

```cs
//method to create zip file (just a sample)
public static void AppendToZip(SomeType encryptedData)
{
   using (Package zip = Package.Open(@"C:\myarchive.zip", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
   {
      Uri uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri("/files/test.enc", UriKind.Relative));

      try
      {
    part = zip.GetPart(uri);
      }
      catch
      {
      }

      if (part == null)
      {
         part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "", CompressionOption.Maximum);
      }

      using (Stream dest = part.GetStream())
      {
         //how to write encryptedData to destination stream?
      }
   }
}

//sample method for encrypting a file
private static void Encrypt(string inputFile, string cryptFile, byte[] passwordBytes, byte[] saltBytes)
{
   FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);

   RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();

   AES.KeySize = 256;
   AES.BlockSize = 128;


   var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
   AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
   AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
   AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

   AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

   CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

   FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

   int data;
   while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
   {
      cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
   }

   fsIn.Close();
   cs.Close();
   fsCrypt.Close();
}
```

Comment: Compression should usually be done before encryption, as it usually achieves a higher compression ratio. (Depending on data type, of course.) Obviously this is not always possible, but maybe it is for you.

Comment: So is your goal to encrypt the file first and store it at rest in the zip?  Are you using the zip for archival or compression?

Comment: Two things:
  - Use Zip.PartExists instead of a try catch block - unnecessarily costly that way
  - 1 byte at a time is also costly - better to take a block of 4096 and turn down the churn, especially when you're looking at a 10GB file

Answer (score 2):

Try this out - play around with block size for performance.  I did this with a 3.5 GB ISO successfully.  However the zip file is much larger compressing encrypted content, so as the other guy said you're better compressing the file FIRST and then encrypting it.  But I don't know your requirements, so here's this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.IO.Packaging;

namespace ZipTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Block size we apply to all reads / writes
            const int BLOCK_SIZE = 65536;

            // The zip file we're using
            var zipFileName = @"C:\temp\ZipSO\MyZip.zip";

            // Password for encryption
            var password = "ThisIsMyPassword";

            // Name of temp file where we'll encrypt the file first
            var intermediateFile = @"C:\temp\ZipSO\Intermediate_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            // File we're encrypting / adding to archive
            var inputFile = @"C:\temp\ZipSO\InputFile.txt";

            // Salt for encryption
            var salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

            // For the new / existing package part
            PackagePart part = null;

            // Open the archive
            using (var zip = Package.Open(zipFileName, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                // Uri for the part
                var uri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri("/files/test.enc", UriKind.Relative));

                // Get existing part if found, or create new
                if (zip.PartExists(uri))
                    part = zip.GetPart(uri);
                else
                    part = zip.CreatePart(uri, "", CompressionOption.Maximum);

                // Encrypt the file first
                var passBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
                using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(intermediateFile, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    var key = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passBytes, salt, 1000);
                    var keySize = 256;
                    var blockSize = 128;

                    var aes = new System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged()
                    {
                        KeySize = keySize,
                        BlockSize = blockSize,
                        Key = key.GetBytes(keySize / 8),
                        IV = key.GetBytes(blockSize / 8),
                        Padding = System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.Zeros,
                        Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.CBC
                    };

                    using (var fsSource = new System.IO.FileStream(inputFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var cs = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream(fs, aes.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            var readBytes = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
                            int read;
                            while ((read = fsSource.Read(readBytes, 0, BLOCK_SIZE)) != 0)
                            {
                                cs.Write(readBytes, 0, read);
                            }
                            cs.Close();
                        }
                        fsSource.Close();
                    }
                    fs.Close();
                }

                // Now add it to the archive
                using (var p = part.GetStream(System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    using (var source = new System.IO.FileStream(intermediateFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                    using (var bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(p))
                    {
                        var readBytes = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
                        int read;
                        while ((read = source.Read(readBytes, 0, BLOCK_SIZE)) != 0)
                        {
                            bw.Write(readBytes.Take(read).ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Clean up the intermediate
                System.IO.File.Delete(intermediateFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I think, this is the best way in most scenarios. But is there any solution to do it completely in memory, with no temporary file?

Comment: I'm sure you could, but the memory cost would be very high.  In this scenario my page file ran about 500MB between writes to the zip file, which as I mentioned grew to about 5 GB for a 3.8 GB ISO.  I'm not sure what kind of data you're encrypting / packaging but I'm strongly encourage you to use secondary storage for your file streams instead of MemoryStreams based on what you've described.

In the scenario above you could replace writable file streams with System.IO.MemoryStream but again cost will be very high - and you risk buffer overruns depending on what memory you have at your disposal.

Comment: Any further information required for this one, or are you ok with my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was out of office with no access to Internet.

Thanks for your time but this is my goal - to load large file and encrypt it in memory.

Comment: I want to use no temporary file, because it means I need three files at all - the first one is the original file, the second one for a temporary file and the third one for an output. And my memory and disk space is limited. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Where I used `System.IO.FileStream` up above you could replace it with `System.IO.MemoryStream` and write in-memory.  However I'm concerned that a 10GB file is going to swell your memory footprint.  If you are ultimately looking to write this message out to a user (like via the web) you could call the `GetResponseStream()` method on your `HttpWebResponse` and direct the data there, using the response as your target instead of memory.

The challenge for you is you want to encrypt the data and compress it.  You have two serial operations that it sounds like you want to run in parallel.  No?